# How to do Email Hosting with Cloud apps (heroku)?

Tags: email, heroku, web-hosting

I run several websites on rackspace and have been slowly converting the sites to web apps on heroku, however my clients still need email@theirdomain.com.

Most of the solutions I see on heroku are for sending notifications and not hosting email services.

Most of the email only services seem to be about email marketing not hosting.   Is there a way for me to drop the rackspace server and still provide email hosting to my clients?

Comment: this is not really a stackoverflow questions as such but i'll answer it because that is exactly what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: this would be more appropriate for serverfault. although service suggestions questions are discouraged in general on SE

Comment: but well I remember it was quite a horror when google shut down their  free service. so glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try free hosting for email at http://domains.live.com You need to be able to change your mx server to do that. Its quite simple. The interface is great and comes with smtp

Comment: Thank you Somesh. I will check that out and if not a stack overflow question where might I have posted it?